# How to store only line matching grep to a variable

Tags: bash, unix, grep

Let's say I have a file with this text:

```
FName;LName;PhNm;FxNm;Eml
FN2;LN2;PN2;FN2;E2
```

I store a queried phrase in a variable x, and I use grep -n in order to find the line number and store it in another variable y, in order to then output the contents of the found line. E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
read x
y=$(grep -n "$x" test.txt)
echo "$y"
```

However, this also outputs the phrase x.

```
2:LN2
```

How do I suppress that, and only get the line number, in order to then output the contents of the line as I wish to format them?

Comment: Remember also you are reading a variable `x` but passing the literal string `x` to `grep`. It should have been `$x`

Comment: Good call. I forgot that while writing the example.

Comment: @Inian I think the correct answer is a combination between your comment and my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe `cut -f1 -d:` to get only the number:

```
y=$(grep -n "x" test.txt | cut -f1 -d:)
```

Run `man cut` to learn more about it.